# Modify UICollectionView Footer

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application where I display citizens in a UICollectionView. There are two levels of citizens, basic and premium. Premium member are able to view more citizens than basic members. I have a custom footer in the Collection View, which contains an ActivityIndicator and a Label.

```
class CitizensCollectionFooter: UICollectionReusableView {
    @IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loadMoreCitizensLabel: UILabel!
}
```

The loadingIndicator I display when the user scrolls down close to the bottom of the CollectionView if the user has not reached the max limit for his/her membership level. If the basic user has reached the limit, I want to stop the loading indicator and display the Label. Here is a snippet from the code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // Populate more photos when the scrollbar indicator is at 90%
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y + view.frame.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.9 ) {

        // Check if basic member has max citizens loaded
        if (memLevel == Constants.AccessLevel.PREMIUM && citizenArray.count >= Constants.Filters.THUMBS_MAX_LOAD_BASIC) {
            footerView?.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            footerView?.loadMoreCitizensLabel.hidden = false
            footerView?.loadMoreCitizensLabel.text = "Load More Profiles…"
        } else if ( (memLevel >= Constants.AccessLevel.PREMIUM && citizenArray.count < Constants.Filters.THUMBS_MAX_LOAD_PREMIUM) ||
            (memLevel < Constants.AccessLevel.PREMIUM && citizenArray.count < Constants.Filters.THUMBS_MAX_LOAD_BASIC) ) {
                // Limit of citizens not reached for premium or basic, load more citizens
                footerView?.loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
                footerView?.loadMoreCitizensLabel.hidden = true
                populateCitizens()
        } else {
            // Max citizens loaded for premium
            footerView?.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            footerView?.loadMoreCitizensLabel.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I hit this part of the code, the footer view will not update. If I have the loadingIndicator startAnimating from the start within

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
```

It will continue showing and then when the basic citizen reaches the maximum citizens loaded, the label won't appear and the Indicator still shows. Does anyone know how to update a footer of a collection view without having to create the entire collection view again?